# toolchain optimization structure to local variable copy

Tags: compiler-optimization, toolchain

I have structure

```
struct priv_data { int a ; int b }

struct priv_data priv;

int func()
{
    a_val =   priv.a;
    b_val = priv.b;
    printf("a+b=%d , a-b = %d , a*b = %d , a/b = %d",(a_val+b_val),
    (a_val-b_val),(a_val*b_val),(a_val/b_val));
}
```

My Question is does compiler (toolchain) as an intelligence to avoid first copy of `priv.a` to `a_val` since `a_val` is used as read only . In place of `a_val` use `priv.a` where ever it referred , to avoid additional copy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on compiler and also the compilation options. But, I have seen multiple cases where such intermediate variables are optimized when compiled with O2.

Comment: I understand that but , mostly compiler optimization logic pretty must standard right (like number of passes , what is purpose of each pass) etc. is there an easy way to check the same.